# Symony find in array Type

Tags: arrays, doctrine

From a form of symfony I stock several values in a doctrine Array.

Then I want to do a findBy in my controller to find entites with an Id.

My entity:

```
<?php


/**
 * Questionnaire
 *
 */
class Questionnaire
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;


     /**
     * add unit list
     * @Exclude
     * @ORM\Column(name="unitids", type="array")
     */
    private $unitsId = array();



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->unitsId = array();

    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Questionnaire
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }







    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Questionnaire
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }





    /**
     * Set unitsId
     *
     * @param array $unitsId
     * @return Questionnaire
     */
    public function setUnitsId($unitsId)
    {
        $this->unitsId = $unitsId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get unitsId
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getUnitsId()
    {
        return $this->unitsId;
    }


}
```

What I want to do in my controller is to find all questionnaires which have the X unitId in UnitsId.

I tried : 
$entities = $em->getRepository('Questionnaire')->findBy(array('unitsId'=>$unitId ));

But it does not work. 
Is theire a way to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello @user227450 do You have a QuestionnaireRepository Class?? If not, create it,
Also You have to map to you Questionnaire Class  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Name\NameBundle\Entity\QuestionnaireRepository")

Comment: Yes of course. I just remoe the tag for the post. How can I do a search in the Repository ?

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't do this with a Query, first You have to recover the Questionnaire object, then you have to iterate for the array because Doctrine Saves in database the array serialized and it is a lot of garbage, so You can't query directly.

1. find the questionarie.
2. Doctrine unserialize the array automatically
3. Iterate in the array and find the correct id.
4. return the result.

I Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is the only solution ? I would like to avoid it because i'm scared of memory consumption if theire is to many lines in my result before iterating.

Comment: HI @user227450, I think is the only solution, but I'm not completly sure because Serialize objects are complex for the querybuilder. 
You can use ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); before the instruction to remove memory limitation and don't get the fatal error Memory exceeded

Comment: Yes I think I have to create another table a do more clean things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) to fetch objects from joined query.